# Accessibility: Main page navigation contains h2, h1 heading is below

Tags: html, accessibility, semantic-markup

Consider this markup:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

    <head>
    </head>

    <body>
        <header>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="/">
                            <h2>Home</h2>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="/other">
                            <h2>Other</h2>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
        <main>
            <h1>Page Title</h1>
        </main>
    </body>

</html>
```

This markup is "fine" but, if I understood correctly, neither accessible nor semantically correct/recommended. The issue is with the `h2` appearing before `h1`, which creates a confusing document outline:

```
1. Untitled BODY
  1. Home
  2. Other
2. Page Title
```

However the obvious intended outline is:

```
1. Page Title
  1. Home
  2. Other
```

The naive way to achieve this would be to just "move" the whole `nav` somewhere after the `h1`, either inside `main` or after it. But this is not how I want my page to look like, I obviously want my navigation **above** my main page content. Of course I could use CSS to somehow move the `nav` visually up, but that doesn't seem correct either.

My question is: What is the most common, but accessible solution to this "dilemma"? Note that I definitely want the `nav` to keep using `h2` (or any other heading level), as that is, as far as I know, the recommended "semantic" way. This way, the navigation links will also show up in the document outline. Is there some way to just tell a screen reader or browser that some headings should "swap" position in the document outline, maybe through some `aria-` attributes? Is there some alternative I'm missing?

One solution I thought of, but "feels" wrong to me:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

    <head>
    </head>

    <body>
        <header>
            <h1>
                Page Title
            </h1>
            <nav>
                <h2>
                    Page Navigation
                </h2>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="/">
                            <h3>Home</h3>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="/other">
                            <h3>Other</h3>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
        <main>
            <h2>Main Content Title</h2>
        </main>
    </body>

</html>
```

This feels a bit verbose but at least results in a correct document outline. Is this really the only way to solve my problem?

Comment: Don't use `h` tags here. It's not semantic, nor correct to do so. Your `nav` element is what is important for accessibility. Style the nav links how you want to - without those tags. _Note that I definitely want the nav to keep using h2 (or any other heading level), as that is, as far as I know, the recommended "semantic" way._ That is wrong.

Comment: So the navigation items should not show up in a document outline in your opinion? @disinfor

Comment: The navigation does not need to be in the document outline. The document outline is for displaying the content tree of the actual content. In fact, having the navigation in the document outline would probably lead to confusion since the user would be presented with elements that are not relevant to reading. In fact, you should include a single link *prior* to the menu for skipping to content which would be included in the document outline. This really isn't opinion - but rather the correct use of the document outline.

Comment: Alright, seems reasonable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way to mark up this kind of content (in terms of semantics and accessibility) is as follows—

```
<header>
  <nav aria-label="Main Navigation">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Lorem</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Ipsum</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
<main>
  <h1>Page Title</h1>
  <p>Additional page content...</p>
</main>
```

Navigation items should not be marked up as headings. A list of links is all that is necessary. [See this example from the Mozilla documentation on the navigation element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/nav#examples).

If you want to add a hidden label for the navigation for assistive technologies, you can add an `aria-label` attribute to the `<nav>` element, as detailed in [this example from the W3C Accessibility Guidelines Working Group](https://www.w3.org/WAI/GL/wiki/Using_aria-label_to_provide_labels_for_objects#Example_1). Additionally, this approach avoids needing to add a heading out of order.

Finally, be sure to include the document title (`<h1>`) *within* the `<main>` element, as in [this example from the Mozilla documentation on the main element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/main#example).

Answer (score -2):

https://www.accessibility-developer-guide.com/examples/headings/visually-hidden-headings/ is answering most of the questions I have here.

Turns out it's fine to just move headings you don't want to be displayed, but read by screen readers, off the screen. This way a correct document outline can be achieved as well, without being visually verbose.

My solution I will probably use from now on would be:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

    <head>
    </head>

    <body>
        <header>
            <h1 class="visually-hidden">
                Page Title
                <!-- this can also just contain a logo -->
            </h1>
            <nav>
                <h2 class="visually-hidden">
                    Page Navigation
                </h2>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="/">
                            <h3>Home</h3>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="/other">
                            <h3>Other</h3>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
        <main>
            <h2>Main Content Title</h2>
        </main>
    </body>

</html>
```

The `visually-hidden` class would then be described by:

```css
.visually-hidden {
    position: absolute;
    left: -10000px;
    width: 1px;
    height: 1px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: As @disinfor pointed out, heading elements should not be used for navigation items. Semantically, they should just be anchors in a list.